# Is it bad practice to have an overloaded method with a static and non-static version of the same method?

Tags: java, class, oop, static, static-methods

I am working on a CRUD application in Java currently. I have classes that correlate with each table in my database. Is it bad practice to have the same method with both static and non-static versions of the method overloaded? To keep things simple, I have the non-static versions simply calling the static version and using the this keyword to pass in the parameters.

Rough example below:

```
class Account {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public static void insertDB(String firstName, String lastName){
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            String sql = "insert into account (firstName, lastName) values(?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    public void insertDB(){
        insertDB(this.firstName, this.lastName);
    }
}
```

This seems like the best way to account for needing to use a method with or without an instance of the class existing. If this is bad practice, should it be avoided by simply creating an instance of the Account class every time I need to use one of its methods?

Comment: It’s a perfectly acceptable practice.  I’m pretty sure it occurs in a number of places in Java SE.

Comment: Looks ok, accept for the direct use of `DriverManager`, as that will make it hard to unit test (but that is unrelated to your question).

Comment: @AndrewS How would one go about making the connection easier to unit test?

Comment: Don't use a static method!  And do you use dependency injection!  But if a static method is absolutely required, then _PowerMock_ could be used to mock the result of `DriverManager` to return a mock `Connection`.  In general, I tend to consider the need for the use of _PowerMock_ as a code/design smell.

Comment: You need to wrap your static method and get it called from a class that is instantiable. If you feel the need for powermock consider the michael feathers WEWLC 
book instead.